# Connection is failing between Oracle 10g and JDK 1.6.0.18

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

Following is my `getConnection` class:

```
package connection;
import java.sql.*;

public class getConnection {

    public static Connection getConnectionBuilder(){
        String username="system";
        String password="root";
        try{

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            try {
                Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE",username,password);
                return conn;

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println("Problem in getting connection with URL or username or password");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
            System.err.println("Error loading driver");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Another 2 JSP pages are there in my project which are using this connection class. But I am getting error `Error loading driver`. As per my connection class, this error means Driver is not getting loaded properly. My Oracle is 10g, JAVA is JDK 1.6.0.18 and I am using both ojdbc14.jar and ojbc6.jar. Still I am getting the same error.

**STACKTRACE GENERATED**:

```
15 Aug, 2014 10:20:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Bank_Web] threw     exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /Insert_To_Account_Master.jsp at line 24

21: System.out.println("blah");
22: 
23: 
24: Connection con=getConnection.getConnectionBuilder();
25: PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("Insert into  account_master(name,acct_opn_date,cif_id,address) values(?,?,?,?)");
26: pstmt.setString(1,fullname);
27: pstmt.setString(2,accopndate);


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver
at connection.getConnection.getConnectionBuilder(getConnection.java:11)
at   org.apache.jsp.Insert_005fTo_005fAccount_005fMaster_jsp._jspService(Insert_005fTo_005fAccount_005fMaster_jsp.java:86)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Shouldn't use two Oracle driver JARs; just one.  It should be ojdbc6.jar, because the "6" means "JDK6".  Terrible code - you use the system password in an app?  In plain text?  Who closes this connection?  Why aren't you using a JNDI connection pool, managed by your app server?  Are you using Tomcat?  The ojdbc6.jar should be in the Tomcat server /lib.

Comment: Cany you add the whole stacktrace please?

Comment: If it's a web application, make sure to drop the jar in WEB-INF/lib folder. Otherwise, the jar won't be in your classpath at runtime.

Comment: @Jens, I have added the stacktrace generated.

Comment: @Mistu4u where your jar are located?

Comment: I have added them in the project buildpath and they are physically located in other folder of another drive i.e. in F drive.

Comment: Then yes, your problem seems to be that your jar isn't in WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: Java 6 update 18 is really old.  You should consider it upgrading it to the latest version of Java 6 update 45, if not installing a current version of Java.